# Pandas sort_values function takes lot of memory without any assignment operation

Tags: python, pandas

Let assume I have large dataframe df with column 'A','B','C'. I sort it using

```
df.sort_values('A')
```

here df is large and after this operation main memory size increases drastically. I dont save result into any new variable. I tried `gc.collect` but it is not helping to release memory. any suggestions?

Comment: Okay... but `.sort_values()` by default returns a sorted *copy* of your DF... if you don't want a copy - why not use `df.sort_values('A', inplace=True)` ?

Comment: I believe that, contrary to what it may seem, ```inplace=True``` also creates an intermediate copy of your df, meaning that you'll see a peak in memory usage in any case, since 2 dfs coexist in all scenarios. If you're not assigning this new sorted df to any var, I don't see how memory usage could increase apart from during whatever calculation you are performing with your sorted df. I.e. two dfs (unsorted and sorted) coexist during your one-liner calculation. However, if the sorted one is not assigned to any new var, the memory should be released straight after.

Comment: I have the same problem. Using `inplace=True` there is an increment in the memory use of a 10%. It is not going to look well in the comment but this is the memory_profiler output: 
`Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents                                                                                                                               
============================================================        
    65   5097.0 MiB    450.7 MiB           1       df.sort_values([col1, col2], inplace=True)  `